# Force close with in app billing function

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have uploaded my app to Google Play, after few updates I'm getting error like this

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wipeout.simplegame/com.wipeout.simplegame.MainMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.wipeout.simplegame.screen.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:238)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
```

Here is my MainMenu.java

```
private ImageView advertButton;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        advertButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.advertOffButton);

    advertButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //line 238

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mHelper != null) {
                mHelper.flagEndAsync();
                try {
                    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(MainMenu.this, SKU_PREMIUM, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I set `flagEndAsync()` to the public in IabHelper, because I saw that helps somebody, but my problem still exist. Whole code in app billing I copied from Google developer site, so I don't know where is the problem. For me and few test accounts everything works great, but some people have problems with it.

Comment: It looks like the most likely culprit is a `null` `MainMenu` object.  Have you checked that that is not null?

Comment: So, I should before `if (mHelper != null)` statement check that `if (MainMenu != null)` ? MainMenu.java of course is a standard android activity, so I think it's unnecessary

Comment: I do not know how to check if it works.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?  It's entirely possible the nullref is occuring inside of the `launchPurchaseFlow` call.

Comment: This is all what google dev console shows.

Comment: Your MainMenu is being created at some point, however the advertButton variable is null, since you can't call a method on a 'null' object (setOnClickListener), you are getting a NullPointerException

Comment: Do you have overloaded resource variants of activity_main_menu.xml that don't have advertButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make it like this

`findViewById(R.id.advertOffButton).setOnClickListener(MainMenu.this);`

and add overrided method onClick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   if (view.getId() == R.id.advertButton) {
      if (MainMenu.class != null) {
       if (mHelper != null) {
        mHelper.flagEndAsync();
        try {
               mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(MainMenu.this, SKU_PREMIUM, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        }
       }
    }
}
}
```

of course you can try to make this if-statements with AND operator :)

Answer (score 0):

Your AdvertButton is likely `null`.  Make sure you are getting it through `activity.findViewById(R.id.advertButton);` before using it.

Comment: I edited main post, so before `advertButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()` i should check that advertButton != null by if statement?